# Menu not showing up using Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have the newest Foundation complete version and I am following this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RK_k__4Y4TU
I am trying to get a menu but there is nothing on my website at all. It is just blank.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
    scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content></div>  

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to tell from only looking at your HTML, are you sure the css is loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and only mistake is you have written `off-canvas` insted of `off-canvas-wrap`.
No class exist with name `off-canvas`.
`<div class="off-canvas-wrap position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>`